# usage of "Since the last X years"

Tags: word-usage

Is this correct?
"Since the last X years, Y is being used as ...".
Meaning that Y has been used during the last X  years, but also that it has been used for the first time only X years ago.

this seems incorrect:
"Over the last X years, Y is being used as ...".
"over" + passive present continuous feels weird for me.

And by using:
"Over the past X years, Y have been used as ...",
I think, would not have the same meaning as with "since".

Please, advice!

Comment: *Since* is wrong for your context. (Although that string of words could work in a different sentence:  "Since the last 10 years have been wet, we expect the next few years to be drier.")  Use "Over the last X years, Y was used" or "For the last X years, Y has been used"

Comment: I totally agree. Since cannot be used in the example you provided, user3416265.

Comment: I agree with Jim's last version,  *"For the last X years, Y has been used"*.  That is the natural sentence that a native speaker would use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Do you have any suggestion to replace the first part of the sentence, so that I can use passive present continuous next.
"BLAHBLAH ..., Y is being used"
I want to point out that Y is being used more and more starting from X years (in the past).
"For the last X years" and "Over the last X years"  seem not to convey this message.
Thanks.

Comment: The use of Y has been increasing over the past X years.

Comment: No, because when you say "For the last X years," you're saying that it's from that earlier time until now.  This is why you have to say "Y has been used" -- that's the correct tense for some time in the past until now.  How about "Y has been and continues to be used . . . "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd alter the statement to

*"Since its introduction X years ago, Y has been used..."*

Or, slightly restructured (as some people may feel more natural):

*"Y has been used ... since its introduction X years ago."*

(You could swap out "first use", "invention", "discovery", etc., instead of "introduction"...whatever you prefer.)

Alternatively, you could go with, "Starting X years ago, Y has been used..."

"Since" (in both preposition and conjunction roles) is more commonly paired with a singular event serving as the anchoring point of reference, and not a time period. "Since" already conveys the duration of time, and simply needs the starting/anchoring point (the event/date which happens to have been X years ago). So just provide the actual event/date (its first use, its invention, its discovery, Jan 1, 1983, etc.).

Per [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/since):

***Since***

**preposition**

4. continuously from or counting from:

   *It has been warm since noon.*
5. between a past time or event and the present:

   *There have been many changes since the war.*

**conjunction**

6. in the period following the time when:

   *He has written once since he left.*
7. continuously from or counting from the time when:

   *He has been busy since he came.*

Answer (score 0):

The usage of "**since**" has been an issue for many English learners, for the French, for example, since I know how its equivalent term in French is used. It often causes confusion among many other non-native speakers as well.

In the context in which it's been used here, "since" means "starting from", and needs a specific date, time or period.

**Examples:**

Since August 1
Since noon
Since the beginning of the 21st century

Therefore, one cannot say "since many years" or "since X years". In similar contexts, *since* is replaced by ***for***.

**Examples:**

For (the last/past) ten years, I've been a vegetarian.
We haven't seen each other for almost a decade.
For the most part of 2014, the company made huge profits.

As for the usage of "**over**", we may say:

"We met over the weekend."
"Can we discuss this over lunch?"

It doesn't mean the same thing as "since", as in the above examples.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed I'm a native french speaker, and I was looking for the equivalent for "Depuis X ans" or "Depuis quelques années".

Comment: Oh, I thought so! Depuis dix ans = For (the last) ten years (now). Depuis quelques années = For several years (now).